# Is there any specific model/theory that proposes that the universe is an oracle machine?

Tags: turing-machines, oracle-machines, physics, oracles

Is there any specific (and well known/famous) model/theory that proposes that the universe is an oracle machine?

Physicist Roger Penrose said his book "The Shadows of the Mind"

> It would be just as possible, in principle, to have a universe that runs deterministically as an oracle machine as it would to have one that runs deterministically in a Turing machine

But I could not find any specific model. Do you know of any? Did Turing himself propose that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because philosophy is off-topic on this site.

Comment: This sounds like a question about physics or philosophy to me, too.  "Theories about the universe" are a matter of physics (or philosophy).  We are a site for questions about computer science, not physics or computer science.